# Problem with hyperref and cleveref

Tags: hyperref, cleveref, hyperlink

I'm trying to put an image that is link to a youtube video. The problem is that when I load the hyperref package it doesn't compile and get a huge error. I loaded the hyperref before cleveref as should be.

My latex consists only of a fig folder, a main.tex and a config.tex. This is the config.tex:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%% PACKAGES %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{algorithm2e} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage{listings} % For displaying code
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{cite} % for references
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{setspace}  % spacing
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{float}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%% SETTINGS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%margins
\geometry{letterpaper,
headheight=2cm,
left=2cm,
right=2cm,
top=3cm,
bottom=2cm}
% header and footer
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{\small University Course Name}
\lhead{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{fig/fcfm_die_tight.png}}
\cfoot{\thepage }
% Floats settings
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand\tablename{Tabla}
}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\Crefname{table}{Tabla}{Tablas}
\Crefname{lstlisting}{Listado}{Listados}
\Crefname{equation}{}{}

\newcommand{\projectName}{Algo Interesante}
\newcommand{\students}{Persona1 y Persona2}
\newcommand{\tutor}{Persona}
\newcommand{\teachingAssistant}{Charles}
\newcommand{\professor}{Robert}

\newcommand{\myTitle}{%
\begin{center}
{\Large \bfseries
\projectName
}\\\vspace{0.5cm}
{\normalsize 
Estudiante(s): \students\\
Tutor: \tutor\\
Profesor Auxiliar: \teachingAssistant\\
Profesor de Cátedra: \professor
}
\end{center}}
```

And I'll copy here the first and important part of the main.tex:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt]{article}

% Si tuvieses que agregar un paquete extra a tu documento, por favor hazlo dentro del archivo config.tex
\input{config.tex}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{argmax}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\maximize}{max}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\expectation}{\mathbb{E}}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabla}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Listado}
\captionsetup{justification=centering,width=0.8\textwidth}


% Ingresa tus datos personales aquí
\renewcommand{\projectName}{\textit{Cool Title}}
\renewcommand{\students}{Max, Dylan and Francis}
\renewcommand{\tutor}{Charles}
% Esto genera el título con la información anterior
\myTitle


\section{Introducción}

Las formas de vida inteligentes son capaces de aprender...

A lot of irrelevent text...

\end{document}
```

Without hyperref everything works perfectly. But I need to insert an image as a link to a youtube video. With hyperref I get this error:

```
No PDF
This compile didn’t produce a PDF. This can happen if:
There is an unrecoverable LaTeX error. If there are LaTeX errors shown below or in the raw logs, please try to fix them and compile again.
The document environment contains no content. If it’s empty, please add some content and compile again.
This project contains a file called output.pdf. If that file exists, please rename it and compile again.

Argument of � has an extra }.        ./main.tex, 23‬

<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.23 \section{Introducción}
                            
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.
```

[image]

Comment: don't use \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}, delete the line.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Wow! Thanks Ulrike, that worked perfectly!